# Ist es in Ordnung, danach zu fragen, welche Mundart ein bestimmter Text ist?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, dialect

In einer Ausgabe von Grimms Märchen in zwei Bänden vom Insel-Verlag Leipzig von 1919 sind ein paar Märchen in Mundart enthalten. Nun würde ich gern identifizieren, um welche Mundart oder Mundarten es sich handelt.

Ist die Frage danach auf der Hauptseite zulässig?

Wenn dem so ist, würde ich eine eingescannte Seite liefern, sowie eine Abschrift dieser Seite.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ich sehe keinen Grund, das nicht zu fragen. Es geht weder um eine direkte Übersetzung, noch um eine Antwort, die man aus z.B. Wörterbüchern leicht entnehmen könnte. Solange sich deine Kopie, was das Volumen angeht, im Bereich eines *Zitats* bewegt, sollte auch das Urheberrecht nicht dagegen sprechen.

Comment: Ich denke urheberrechtsmäßig ist ohnehin alles abgelaufen was da sein könnte, sowohl vom Verlag (1919) als auch von den Brüdern Grimm (neunzehntes Jahrhundert). Aber ich wollte ohnehin nur Ausschnitte liefern. Danke. Dann bereite ich das mal vor.

Comment: Falls der Autor der Mundart-Märchen identifizierbar ist, ist keineswegs gesagt, daß das Urheberrecht schon abgelaufen ist. In Deutschland dauert es 70 Jahre ab dem Tod des Autors; es ist absolut möglich, daß jemand 1919 Märchen geschrieben und dann noch bis mindestens 1946 gelebt hat.

Comment: @chirlu: das schon, aber ich denke nicht, daß die Brüder Grimm noch leben. Kurzum, das eigentliche Werk ist gemeinfrei, jedoch womöglich die entsprechende Drucklegung (Satz usw.) nicht.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: Das setzt voraus, daß diese Texte von den Grimms sind und der Verlag nicht irgendwelche anderen Texte mit hinein gepackt hat, wie das bei solchen Sammlungen öfter vorkommt. Um den Satz brauchst du dir allerdings keine Gedanken zu machen, Leistungsschutzrechte dafür gibt es nur im Bereich der Musiknoten und, jetzt, der Presse (Dauer hier ein Jahr, glaube ich).

Answer (score 3):

Definitiv **ja.** Das Erkennen von verschiedenen Mundarten behandelt meines Erachtens eindeutig »finer points of the German language.« Oftmals gibt es zwei verwandte, ähnliche Mundarten, die sich nur anhand weniger Schibboleths unterscheiden lassen (zum Beispiel *gsi/gwea*, die wohl Schwäbisch und Alemannisch unterscheiden). Manchmal kann man das mit ausreichend Wissen sogar bis auf das Dorf einkreisen. In allen Fällen ist es etwas, das »Experten« beantworten können (und vielleicht sogar gerne tun).

Es sollte sich meines Erachtens idealerweise um einen durchgängigen Text handeln, der in einem konsistenten Dialekt geschrieben worden ist. Irgendwo auf der Hauptseite gibt es eine Frage, in der lauter Zeilen jeweils in ihrem eigenen Dialekt gehalten worden sind; das halte ich für eine weniger passend, aber immer noch ausreichend.